# Keep synchronize application instances within network on diffrent actions

Tags: vb.net

I develop application which will be multi-user application including central database. Every user will be having his own copy. All users will be working within same network. As long as i am fine to handle one application instance using either events or interfaces to trigger some actions against specific user actions i have no idea how to handle other's users instances towards other users actions.

Let's imagine one user is deleting some data when meantime other users are doing something with those data. In this case they should be aware of and their applications should react e.g close form or whatever else. As i mentioned i can easly handle it with either events or interfaces along one instance but the problem comes how to handle other application instances within network to avoid situations i mentioned. How do you handle such things?

Hope it's clear and awaiting any advice from your side.

Comment: you can save all edits in another table with column of the primary key of the original record.
and than view all edits in your application (ordered by dates and hours in datatgridview for example).

Comment: i was thinking about that but this or similar like to store something like queue table so every instance could read in background as asynchronous task which could read information out of it and allow/dissalow/reject some actions but this is something which would cost me a lot of time to implement in this app. I would consider more like something to communicate between those instances and call/exchange information either by events/interfaces actions to be triggered like within one instance. Is there possibile to do so?

Comment: do you have an application server? its desktop app? how many users?

Comment: @jonathana It's desktop winforms application. Every user will be having his copy on his computer. Database in centralized on server. Around 40-50 users. P.S WHat about WCF?

Comment: its very small i would go for saving edits.. but if you have an application server  WCF is the right way, you can create server side application that each user will pass (via wcf or other communication protocol / web service) the current record that is editing right now and other user will be able to "check" record current status.  you didnt mantion if you have application server (sql server is not app server)

Comment: @jonathana what do you mean by application server? P.S sql server db will be on phisical separated server which all users will be connected to from their computers.

Comment: application server is a server that has OS you can access and you can run processes an services on it (probably windows server OS in your case). its "sitting" on your local network, every users need to have access to it. its not a task for SQL server.

Comment: its very hard to explain architecture and design in comments...but i found something for you: http://vbcity.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Components.ImageFileViewer/CommunityServer.Discussions.Components.Files.55/6646.connection.GIF_2D00_750x0.png                                                                            good luck with your project!

Comment: i have windows server which sql server runs, i can also use it for WCF. My idea is to create that WCF project and exchange information between diffrent instances of my app. So the idea could be if some user is e.g deleting something then i could send information to WCF service and store those info somwhere and for other users all instances could listen asynchronously for every second and ask WCF services to get info about if something is going on with those data. What do you think is it good idea? Certainly this service would be runnin on my sever besides db.

Comment: i think that technicaly its possible and its good idea for vast application with a lot of traffic. as to your application if the chances are high that user will try to edit record that was deleted right now i would go for it but if its rare case i would catch edit on a deleted record and prompt the user that the record is not exist anymore (less user experience but it is a rare case) also if you are a single developer its much more development time and maintenance.

Comment: dont understand me wrong, communication to a server and tasks made by the server are must,  but consider where to focus when you are developing the server side.

Comment: It depends on your application. You need to research optimistic and pessimistic concurrency, and locking.